# Counting Number of Specific Outputs of a Function

Tags: matlab

If I have a matrix and I want to apply a function to each row of the matrix. This function has three possible outputs, either x = 0, x = 1, or x > 0. There's a couple things I'm running into trouble with...

1) The cases that output x = 1 or x > 0 are different and I'm not sure how to differentiate between the two when writing my script.

2) My function isn't counting correctly? I think this might be a problem with how I have my loop set up?

This is what I've come up with. Logically, I feel like this should work (except for the hiccup w/ the first problem I've stated)

`[m n] = size(matrix);

    a = 0; b = 0; c = 0;

    for i = 1 : m

    x(i) = function(matrix(m,:));

        if x > 0

            a = a + 1;

        end

        if x == 0

            b = b + 1;

        end

        if x == 1

            c = c + 1;

        end

end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you probably have an error in line 4. It probably should be `i` instead of `m`.

```
x(i) = function(matrix(i,:));
```

You can calculate `a`, `b` and `c` out of the loop:

```
a = sum(x>0);
b = sum(x==0);
c = sum(x==1);
```

If you want to distinguish `x==1` and `x>0` then may be with `sum(xor(x==1,x>0))`.

Also you may have problem with precision error when comparing double values with 0 and 1.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me fix my problem and using the sum command I was able to get rid of all those if statements and make the script much shorter.